# Volume Boost in My Android Application

Tags: android, eclipse, audio, volume

I need to create an application for android platform possibly to run on V2.3 or later. I need to provide an audio boost button in my application, whenever an user push this button, it should increase the volume of audio player significantly above system defined maximum volume (specially for some poor quality audio files.). I am totally helpless at this point. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: What do you mean by "poor quality audio"? Do you mean the recorded level is too low? If so, you could gain up the signal before playback.

Comment: Is your app playing back the audio?

Comment: @jaket         I mean, the audio tracks produces very low volume even at 256kbps

Comment: @marko         I used to play Audio books in my application (.mp3 or .m4a)